# SignInManager constructor changes when not in ASP.NET Core web project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

## Description

I have created a custom [`SignInManager`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L33) in order to override the [`SignOutAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L241) method. It works perfectly when in an ASP.NET Core web project.

I am changing my application architecture to isolate all Identity Framework logic into a Service layer. Therefore, I want to move my `CustomSignInManager` out of the ASP.NET Core project and into a Service class library project. The Service project has references to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` packages.

## Problem

When I move the `CustomSignInManager` out of the ASP.NET Core project, and into a class library, I get the following two compiler errors:

1. *The type or namespace name `IUserConfirmation<>` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Services]csharp(CS0246)*
2. *`SignInManager<>` does not contain a constructor that takes 7 arguments [Services]csharp(CS1729)*

As shown in the source code, the [`SignInManager`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L33) constructor does indeed take 7 arguments, and [`IUserConfirmation`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IUserConfirmation.cs) is the 7th argument.

## Code

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/zwoolli/SignInManagerQuestion/tree/main) to replicate this error. Both the `Web` and `Service` projects have the same [`CustomSignInManager`](https://github.com/zwoolli/SignInManagerQuestion/blob/main/Web/CustomSignInManager.cs) class. But for reasons unknown to me, the `Service` project `CustomSignInManager` has the two compile time errors mentioned above.

### Custom sign in manager

```
using Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Services.Identity;
public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
        IUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser> confirmation) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation) {}
    public override async Task SignOutAsync()
    {
        await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    }
}
```

## Question

What is my `Service` class library missing such that:

- the compiler cannot find the `IUserConfirmation<>` type?
- the compiler thinks the `SignInManager` constructor does not take 7 arguments?

Comment: An environment.  Start the user with a service account.  The default is to start a service as System which does not have an environment.

Comment: I'm confused. Start what user with a service account? How does that help a class library compile?

Comment: The environment contains paths where to locate files.  The error indicate the libraries cannot be found.  You can open the csproj with notepad and check where the libraries are located in working code and then make sure the locations are valid in the service.  The csproj has references to the Environment variables.

Comment: From what I can tell, the csproj file shows what packages are referenced. But I do not have any environment variables in the service [`csproj`](https://github.com/zwoolli/SignInManagerQuestion/blob/main/Services/Services.csproj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the answer by [`pfx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75930397/signinmanager-constructor-changes-when-not-in-asp-net-core-web-project/75933211#75933211), the [`services.csproj`](https://github.com/zwoolli/SignInManagerQuestion/blob/55405af5eadaf846e4fe496370db673fe79a388c/Services/Services.csproj#L11) was using an outdated package reference to [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity).

To fix both compile time errors, I removed the old identity package reference,

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
```

and added a [framework reference to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your [`services.csproj`](https://github.com/zwoolli/SignInManagerQuestion/blob/main/Services/Services.csproj) shows that you're using an outdated package reference to
[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity).

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
```

See the notice on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity).

> This GitHub project has been archived. Ongoing development on this project can be found in https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.

---

You should be using [`Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core) with a version that matches your target framework.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="6.0.15" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Referencing the `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` package helped to resolve the first compile time error regarding `IUserConfirmation`. However, the second error still exists. When looking at the metadata for `SignInManager` in the `Web` project, it appears to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package with Version = 7.0.0.0. I cannot find that package on nuget. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like I needed to include a framework reference to [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework). "Projects using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor SDK must reference ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework."